# What are dynamic methods and how is DynamicMethod different from MethodBuilder?

Tags: .net, reflection, clr, reflection.emit, dynamic-method

I've come across dynamic methods a little in reflection-based C# code, and I'm yet to figure out precisely what they are. There specifically seems to be a `DynamicMethod` class that allows the generation and specification of CLR methods at runtime. But then there's also the `MethodBuilder` class. They both seem to do very similar things. Apparently "dynamic assemblies" are `AssemblyBuilder` classes and "dynamic types" are `TypeBuilder` classes. They all reside in the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace in any case.

MSDN seems to have precious little high-level information on this subject. So if someone could explain what dynamic methods are, where exactly all the `XYZBuilder` classes come into play here, and what they're each used for, that would be great. Any other Reflection.Emit types and functionality I should know about would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 18):

I think [the documentation for `DynamicMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx) explains this well:

> You can use the `DynamicMethod` class to generate and execute a method at run time, without having to generate a dynamic assembly and a dynamic type to contain the method. The executable code created by the just-in-time (JIT) compiler is reclaimed when the `DynamicMethod` object is reclaimed. Dynamic methods are the most efficient way to generate and execute small amounts of code.

If you need to dynamically create one or more methods, use `DynamicMethod`. If you want to create whole types, it means you need to create a dynamic assembly (`AssemblyBuilder`), then create a module inside it (`ModuleBuilder`) and then create one or more types (`TypeBuilder`). To create methods inside those types, you would use `MethodBuilder`.

Another difference is GC: `DynamicMethod`s can be always garbage collected and they are collected one by one. That is, any method can be collected as soon as you stop using it. Dynamic assemblies, on the other hand, can be collected only when you specify it (by using [`AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilderaccess.aspx)) and they are always collected assembly by assembly. For example, if you have two types in an assembly, and you use only one of them, the other one can't be collected.

Comment: Doh. I must have missed this when reading the MSDN pages so late. Thanks.